# How to query nested level DOM using javascript and recursive

Tags: html, dom

I have an issue like this and still cant find a solution for it.

I have a DOM query like this

```
#someid .someclass p
```

Below is the DOM

```
<div id='someid'>
  <div class='someclass'>
    <p>
     some text
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I query the p element by just using these 3 API

```
document.getElementById
document.getElementsByClassName
document.getElementsByTagName
```

I want to use recursive in this case until I can get the p element

Thanks everyone for your guidance.

Comment: Why don't you use `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: Im trying to use recursive in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited my answer and my you are looking for something like this:

```js
var targetContent1 = myFunction('someid', 'someclass', 'p')
var targetContent2 = myFunction('anotherId', 'anotherClass', 'span')
console.log('targetContent1', targetContent1)
console.log('targetContent2', targetContent2)

function myFunction(idName, className, tagName) {
            return document.getElementById(idName).getElementsByClassName(className)[0].getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0].textContent;
}
```

```html
<div id='someid'>
    <div class='someclass'>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='anotherId'>
    <div class='anotherClass'>
        <span>Another Tag Text!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I dont want to use querySelector

Comment: can you provide the html structure and be more explicit of what are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

Use these:

```
document.getElementById("someid");
document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
document.getElementsByTagName("p")
```

Comment: Thank you but that not what I want. What I want is to query the p element using the recursive